# Какой ItemsTemplate и ItemsPanel выбрать для Menu

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

Вот, собственно, код XAML:

```
<Menu Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <MenuItem Header="File">
                <MenuItem Header="Field Size">
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding AllMenuItems}" Grid.Column="0">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MenuVM}" >
                                <MenuItem Command="{Binding Activate}" Width="50" Height="25" >
                            <TextBlock  Text="{Binding NameOfField}"></TextBlock>
                        </MenuItem>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
            </MenuItem>
            </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Биндинг ни Command, ни Text'а не срабатывает, в чем ошибка?
Биндинг ItemsSourse работает,отображает 4 элемента типа MenuItem

Comment: а где у вас лежит команда? в классе где и AllMenuItems? если так, то надо биндить по-другому

Answer (score 0):

Вы как-то сильно всё усложняете.

`MenuItem` сам по себе является `ItemsControl`'ом, так что ваш код упрощается до такого:

```
<Menu Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <MenuItem Header="File">
        <MenuItem Header="Field Size" ItemsSource="{Binding AllMenuItems}">
            <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding NameOfField}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Activate}"/>
                </Style>
            </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
        </MenuItem>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Получается такое:

[image: раскрытая менюшка]